# C# "is" operator alternative in Java

Tags: java, casting

in C# when I want to know if an object is an instance of a particular type or not, I can use "is" operator:

```
String foo = "hi :)"
if (foo is String) ...
```

how can I do it in java? (I know I can use try statement, any other way?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java equivalent:

```
String foo = "hi :)"
if (foo instanceof String)
```

Comment: `is` in C# can assign the value to a new instance. `instanceof` seems that only checks for type equality.

Answer (score 12):

You'd use `instanceof` - that's the equivalent of `is` in C#. Note that there's no equivalent of `as`.

See the [JLS section 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) for more details of `instanceof`, but it's basically the same as `is`:

```
// Note: no point in using instanceof if foo is declared to be String!
Object foo = "hello";
if (foo instanceof String)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`instanceof` is the java equivalent to the C# `is` operator.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:-

```
String foo = "hi :)"
if (foo instanceof String)
{
 ......
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (foo instanceof String)
```

I believe is what you're looking for

Answer (score 4):

In java you can use "instanceof" instead of "is"

```
String foo = "hi :)"
if (foo instanceof String)
```